# MVC4 "Cannot await"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, asp.net-mvc-4

The following code snippet is causing a compilation error that I am hard to understand.

> Error 1   Cannot await System.Collections.Generic.List'<BusinessLogic.News>'

Any suggestions?

```
public class NewsController : Controller
{
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index(int page=1)
    {
        NewsNavigator News = new NewsNavigator();
        await News.Load(page);
        ...

        return View(News);
    }
}



    public List<News> Load(int page = DefaultPage, int pageSize = DefaultPageSize, string filter = DefaultFilter)
    {
        //DBLayer_News
        ...
        return LoadedNews;
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Await is applied to the result of a method call that returns a Task.

You cannot call it on News because News isn't a Task.  Create a Task and pass your News.Load method to it.

```
NewsNavigator News = new NewsNavigator();
var newsLoadTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => News.Load(page));
await newsLoadTask;
...
```

Comment: Is there a simpler syntax? In C#5.0 and mvc4

Comment: hmm, i'm not sure... you could make the NewsNavigator class static and get rid of the first line?

Comment: You could always use `await Task.Run(() => News.Load(page));`
Also, be sure that any consumer includes the dll for the return type. Visual Studio 2012 gives an unhelpful error message "Cannot await <datatype name>" when the dll isn't included.

Comment: Static objects have a bad habit of being ready before the rest of the framework (asp.net in this case) is ready to do work. Take a look at dependency injection instead.